# Does Amex or Priority Pass have access to the Saga Lounge at Keflavik Airport?

Tags: airports, lounges, icelandair, kef

I’m pretty new to this domain, so sorry if I do something wrong.

I’m going to fly from Keflavik Airport and I want to stay in the Saga Lounge, but I’m conflicted.

One website says you can use Amex, a different one, you can’t.

So can I use Amex or Priority Pass to get access to this lounge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website for the [Saga Lounge](https://www.icelandair.com/support/airports/saga-lounge/) has a [list of all valid access options](https://pixels.icelandair.com/bltf34de27d20faa624.pdf).

This list includes a number of Visa and Mastercard cards, but does not include either Priority Pass or any American Express cards.

Answer (score 0):

No for Priority Pass. See https://www.prioritypass.com/

Seems also a no for AMEX: https://www.americanexpress.com/idc/en/benefits/the-platinum-card/global-lounge-collection.html but this may depend on the details of your  specific card.

Comment: I have a platinum card

Comment: I suggest checking the benefits website of your specific card, if it's different from the website I have linked or just call them up.